# debian jessie cinnamon default wallpapers showing empty

Tags: debian, gnome3, cinnamon

Im using debian jessie stable with cinnamon as desktop environment.

Previously I was able to change wallpaper from a pre-defined default set of wallpapers already included in system with installation.

But now when I open, `Settings` > `Backgrounds` , there are no default wallpapers showing up. Its empty as in the pic.

[image: Backgrounds empty]

How can I restore the default wallpapers, so I can choose and change the wallpaper?

Answer (score 1):

Default wallpapers from all releases are kept here

http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/

under the directories starting with `mint-backgrounds-`. Expand the `tar.gz` archive and from there put the `./mint-backgrounds-xxxxx/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-xxx` subdirectory in `/usr/share/backgrounds` or (untested) let the deb do it for you.